# Dalvikvm: could not find class referenced from method and get java.lang.verifyerror when run project from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, verifyerror, android-runtime

Hello I am getting error `java.lang.verifyerror`. whenever I run project from android studio.
It happen when I run android application in Android version 4.1 or 4.2
and when I run this app on Nexus 5 its work well. so what is actual issue?

Here is error log which I have been getting during error.

```
09-03 12:49:52.853  21977-21977/com.still.nyapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.VerifyError: com/still/nyapp/cometchat/DaoMaster
        at com.still.nyapp.cometchat.DaoMaster$OpenHelper.onCreate(DaoMaster.java:42)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at com.still.nyapp.application.ApplicationContext.setupDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:67)
        at com.still.nyapp.application.ApplicationContext.onCreate(ApplicationContext.java:36)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

before this i get message in log that is

```
09-04 11:49:44.317    1048-1048/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method          
com.still.nyapp.cometchat.ChatHistoryDao.createTable, referenced from     
method com.still.nyapp.cometchat.DaoMaster.createAllTables
09-04 11:49:44.317    1048-1048/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static 
method 32860: Lcom/still/nyapp/cometchat/ChatHistoryDao;.createTable 
(Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;Z)V
```

Comment: The guy whose answer was down-voted has posted a very useful link with a number of possible reasons. I hope you could read it before the answer was deleted.

Comment: Ya even before post this question i have read that question but can not get actual issue so i have asked this question.

Comment: You could at least show the public what's there at DaoMaster.java:42

Comment: The question got downvoted. That guy has probably revenged. You see, it is difficult to persuade people to spend their time on your problem if you down-vote wrong guesses.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.